# Flex confusing to transform string character by character

Tags: flex-lexer

I want to use flex to transform a string based on simple rules. I have rules like the first character stays the same and the second and third characters might change. Like if the second character was a letter, it becomes the number listed in the rules below. If the third is a digit, it becomes a certain letter.

```
%%
           /*^[a-z] {char *yycopy = strdup( yytext ); unput(yycopy[0]);}*/
[ajs]  {putchar('1');}
[bkt]  {putchar('2');}      
[clu]  {putchar('3');}
[dmv]  {putchar('4');}
[1] {putchar('j');}
[2] {putchar('k');}
[3] {putchar('l');}
[4] {putchar('m');}  /*more number rules till 9*/
%%
int yywrap(void){return 1;}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
             {
             ++argv, --argc;  /* skip over program name */
             if ( argc > 0 )
                     yyin = fopen( argv[0], "r" );
             else
                     yyin = stdin;

             while (yylex());
             }
```

If there are different rules for characters in different positions within the string, how can I use start conditions to change a particular character (i.e. the rules for the second and third character are different).

Comment: I honestly haven't got a clue what you are trying to do. `unput` causes the character to be pushed onto the input stream so that it will be the next character read. If you want to print a character, just print it. (`putchar` is good for that.)

Comment: @rici I messed up. The putchar is exactly what I need. I have to edit this question and ask one about the start condition (so changing a specific character in the string like second or third). My bad man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You switch start condition by using the BEGIN action. Flex never automatically changes start condition, so you when you need to return to the initial start condition (called `INITIAL`), you have to do so explicitly (`BEGIN(INITIAL)`).

You need to declare start condition names in the (f)lex prologue, usually with the `%x` command. (`%s` is also possible but with different semantics. See [the Flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Start-Conditions.html#Start-Conditions) for details.)

You indicate that a start condition applies to a rule by starting the rule with a start condition name in angle brackets. You can put more than one start condition inside the angle brackets; separate them with commas and don't use spaces. Don't put a space after the angle brackets either; they are part of the pattern and (f)lex patterns cannot include unquoted space characters.

`BEGIN` is a macro and it does not require parentheses around the start condition name, but I suggest always using them anyway, so you don't have to worry about what the macro expands to. Start condition names are small integers (either `enum` constants or preprocessor macros) but nothing guarantees their value, so don't make assumptions.

That's about it. So you could implement your astro numerological codifier with:

```
%x SECOND THIRD REST
%%
[a-z]          ECHO; BEGIN(SECOND);
<SECOND>[ajs]  putchar('1'); BEGIN(THIRD);
  /* More SECOND rules */
<THIRD>1       putchar('j'); BEGIN(REST);
  /* More THIRD rules */
<*>.*\n?       ECHO; BEGIN(INITIAL);
```

(I deliberately did not add any `<REST>` rules beacause the fallback at the end covers it. I also deliberately left out the anchor in the first rule because my rules guarantee that the `INITIAL` start condition is 9nly in force at the beginning of a line. See the last rule. The last rule specifies an optional newline in case the file does not end with a newline, which occasionally happens although it's technically invalid.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223564/discussion-on-answer-by-rici-flex-confusing-to-transform-string-character-by-cha).